# Pickle for datapreprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I was going through various tutorials and articles on using pickle on the ml model so that that can be used later.
But I am not able to get something pickle or something similar for data pre- processing. I am doing the preprocessing:

- Changing the datatype of few columns/features.
- Feature engineering.
- Hot Encoding/Dummy variables
- Scaling the data using below code

  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

  ```
  sc = StandardScaler()

  X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)

  X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
  ```

Now, I want to do this for every dataset which I pass for predictions.
Is there any way to do something like pickle to load the data preprocessing steps before I was this to loaded ML model from pickle.

Please guide

Comment: can anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function and saved it a independent file. Then called that function whenever required.

Below is the code on how I am calling the data pre process function

```
from DataPreparationv3 import Data_Preprocess
Base_Data = pd.read_csv('Validate.csv')

DataReady = Data_Preprocess(Base_Data)
```

This solved my problem.

Regards

Sudhir